# Multiple chromedriver instance android

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code looks like this

```
def _launch_android():
    log.info("launching chrome on android device")
    capabilities = {
        'chromeOptions': {
            'androidPackage': 'com.android.chrome',
        }
    }
    log.info("Verifying that android device is connected via USB")
    subprocess.Popen('adb devices')
    p = subprocess.Popen("adb devices", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        log.info(line)
        if re.match("\S+\s+device", line):
            break
        line = p.stdout.readline()
    else:
        raise AssertionError, "Device not connected via USB"


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    return driver
```

Now the issue with this code is when I launch second instance then the first instance closes and I cannot do any operation on that.
e.g

```
a =_launch_android()
b = _launch_android()
a.get("https://www.google.com")
b.get("https://www.facebook.com")
```

here `b.get` works but `a.get` does not.

Comment: chromedriver is automatically launched by selenium if you just create an instance of webdriver.Chrome().... I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do with that code.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I just took the example mentioned here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android
But Yes  webdriver.Chrome()  also works but again this does not solve my problem. I am still having the same issue